# How to keep the background image stick at the bottom if the mobile screen is on landscape?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm developing an Angular web application that is supposed to be mobile responsive. The background image must always be at the bottom. I made this possible for all sizes except for mobile devices that is in the landscape orientation.

I tried researching samples here in Stack Overflow. I tried this, but it only works for the other devices which is great, but not for the problem I have with landscape orientation.

```
:host {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../../../assets/images/...);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What happens is that the background image is only bottom in terms of the height of the view port. It should be at the bottom of the page including the page's height with the scroll (because the view is in landscape).

Comment: can your share your html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried targeting the body tag with your background image?

```
body {
    background-image: url(../../../assets/images/...);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```